# how to find documentation on how random bits and signature are calculated on web api payload

Tags: python, python-3.x, webapi

I'm trying to retrieve json data on the api request, but I'm still confused about the payload generated by the web api, which includes `random` which is in the form of bits or maybe hash, and `signature`. how the documentation of random bits and signatures is calculated.

```
import requests, json
from requests import session
from datetime import datetime
from random_user_agent.user_agent import UserAgent
from random_user_agent.params import SoftwareName, OperatingSystem

software_names = [SoftwareName.CHROME.value]
operating_systems = [OperatingSystem.WINDOWS.value, OperatingSystem.LINUX.value]   
user_agent_rotator = UserAgent(software_names=software_names, operating_systems=operating_systems, limit=100)
user_agents = user_agent_rotator.get_user_agents()
user_agent = user_agent_rotator.get_random_user_agent()
date = datetime.now()
timest = date.timestamp()
session = requests.Session()
url = "https://newapi.55lottertttapi.com/api/webapi/GetNoaverageEmerdList"
data = {
"pageSize":10,
"pageNo":1,
"typeId":1,
"language":0,
"random":"e0697d4c6011408d917314fc67c1f34b",
"signature":"B53CDAE581B7E927B1EC6BB79A44A523",
"timestamp":int(timest)
}
token = open("token.txt").read()
headers = {
"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
"Authorization": f"Bearer {str(token)}",
"User-Agent": f"{str(user_agent)}",
}
a = session.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
b = json.loads(a.text)
print(b)
```

is it some kind of JWT or HMAC? However `random` and `signature` change each time api is called
I hope someone understands how the documentation is calculated or created

untuk menyederhanakan jawaban atas pertanyaan saya, kalian dapat menggunakan ini untuk melihat cara kerja API ini

url website: https://mzplay4.com/#/home/AllLotteryGames/WinGo

url api: https://mzplayapi.com/api/webapi/GetNoaverageEmerdList

Akun yang bisa digunakan:

Masuk Nomor Telepon : 1131247469

Password : Fiqirna87

Comment: Typically, random is just a set of random bytes, and signature is generated by some signing algorithm on everything in the payload except the signature. 

The URLs you give require logins, so it’s impossible to know what signature algorithm in particular

Comment: i have listed account for login hope someone can help me